# Read resources from a resx file

Tags: azure, azure-functions, localizable.strings

I have defined resources files for different languages 
- Resources.de-DE.resx
- Resources.en-US.resx
- Resources.es-ES.resx
- Resources.fr-FR.resx
- Resources.it-IT.resx
- Resources.nl-NL.resx
- Resources.resx

I'm trying to get the localized value of the following string : "Notification created by {user.Name}".

I've tried many things to take the string specified in the right resource file but it doesn't work : it always take the "default" string specified in the Res :

```
    var resourceName = $"MyFunctionApp.Properties.Resources.{plant.LanguageCode}.resx";
    var resourceSet = new ResourceSet(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName));
    string createdBy = resourceSet.GetString(_notificationReportedBy);
```

Or even:

```
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(plant.LanguageCode);
    string longDescription = $"{Resources.NotificationReportedBy} {notificationReported.ValidatedBy }\n{notificationReported.LongDescription}";
```

Maybe Azure Functions don't support properly the resource files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resource files are not currently supported in Azure Functions. This GitHub issue tracks discussion and implementation of such support: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/581